# Canon 430EX II flash: Displaying aperture rather than maximum range?

Tags: canon, flash

I have several Canon 430EX II flash units. Using the custom function menu, I can change the display on the back of the flash to show the aperture value the camera is set to, rather than the maximum range the flash will reach. My question is: why would I want to do this?

Comment: Related: [Why does the Guide Number have a distance given with it?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/84373)

Comment: Related: [What is the quantative relation between flash guide number and ISO?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/16850)

Comment: Related: [How can I calculate the effect of non-TTL flash on exposure?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/29930)